# How to create a dictionary with the unique value of the column and store the values into list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that contains as follows:

```
  A   B  
1 Cat 1
2 Cat 2
3 Dog 1
4 Dog 2
5 Dog 3
6 Dog 4
```

I want to create a dictionary like this with the above dataframe: {'Cat':[1,2], 'Dog':[1,2,3,4]}
Can anyone shed some insight on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method **,** [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method **and** [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method:

```
result=df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
{'Cat': [1, 2], 'Dog': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```